# How to interpret methods with <A,U> RDD<U> in the Scala Spark docs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm reading through the [Spark RDD docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html) based on Scala, and in the Methods section there are values in the Modifier and Type section I don't know how to interpret.  What do these mean in plain english?

```
<U> U
<U> RDD<scala.Tuple2<T,U>>
RDD<T>
<U> RDD<U>
```

Comment: you should really read about generics in scala

Comment: @serejja: That won't help, this is Java syntax, which presumably is what confuses the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<U> U
```

Means that the method uses a type `U` that is unspecified at the time of method definition and returns a value of that type. In the case of `aggregate`:

```
public <U> U aggregate(U zeroValue,
              scala.Function2<U,T,U> seqOp,
              scala.Function2<U,U,U> combOp,
              scala.reflect.ClassTag<U> evidence$32)
```

`U` is the type of the first argument. This is called a parameterized type. It can vary between method calls.

```
<U> RDD<scala.Tuple2<T,U>>
```

Means that the method uses an unspecified type `U` and returns a value of type `RDD<scala.Tuple2<T, U>>`.
Classes can declare parameterized types too, and `RDD` has one called `T`. In the case of `cartesian`:

```
public <U> RDD<scala.Tuple2<T,U>> cartesian(RDD<U> other,
                                   scala.reflect.ClassTag<U> evidence$5)
```

`T` is the parameterized type of the instance of `RDD` that is calling `cartesian`, and `U` is the parameterized type of the instance passed to cartesian as an argument.

Comment: So how do both RDD<T> and <U> RDD<U> both make sense?  What is the <U> adding to the latter that isn't necessary in the former?

Comment: The first `U` in `<U> RDD<U>` is just part of the method signature, stating that there is a type parameter called `U` and `RDD`'s type parameter is `U`. With `RDD<T>`, the `T` refers to the type parameter of the enclosing object. Since `T` is already "declared" by the enclosing object, it does not need to be declared again in a method signature.